# Laravel variable model polymorphic

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I have a table as follows in my database:

```
table area_blocks;

id
owner_type
owner_id
created_at
updated_at
```

in the `owner_type` field it has the Eloquent Model name and the `owner_id` is the id of that model in the database. Example:

```
db: area_blocks

id | owner_type            | owner_id 
1  | App\Models\Title      | 3 
2  | App\Models\Title      | 4
3  | App\Models\Textarea   | 1
```

So I'm expecting when I fetch all of these to also eager load the relevant field from the eloquent model stored in `owner_type`.

Is there an eloquent relationship that can bring back that record from the owner_type field using eager loading? I've tried `$this->morphTo()`, e.g.

```
public function block()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

but that is returned as `null`. Any ideas how this can be done?

Example code;

```
<?php


namespace App\Models;

use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AreaBlocks extends Model
{

    protected $with = ['block'];

    public function block()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

Route::get('/', function(){
    return App\Models\AreaBlocks::all();
});
```

Comment: What's your query? In what model is `block()` defined?

Comment: I've updated the full code above. Block doesn't have a model, I want it to take the model from the owner_type field in the db @JonasStaudenmeir 
so for example area_blocks.id=1 would have the $area_block->block would be the db record for App\Models\Title.id = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the column name/prefix:

```
public function block()
{
    return $this->morphTo('owner');
}
```

Or rename the relationship:

```
public function owner()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Comment: legend that works, have chosen the latter makes more sense!